# Laravel 4: Search keyword from multiple different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three different tables, that have nothing in common (no relationship):

```
events
    id
    title
    description
    ....

pages
    id
    title
    content
    ....

posts
    id
    title
    content
    cat_id
    ....
```

Now I have a search field that need to search the keyword among these three tables and list the search results. How can I do this in Laravel 4.2??

Please help.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join wont help you in this case ,you either run 3 different queries or either use `UNION` to fetch all results 
[UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)